# How can I get values from list of dictionary in a format

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries in which the values are in the list :

```
list_of_dict = [
  {'Node': '1', 'IdRackIp': ['Id1','Id2']},
  {'Node': '2', 'IdRackIp': ['Id3','Id4']}
]
```

I want to get a new list of dictionary in a particular format -

```
list_of_dict =[
  {'Node': '1', 'IdRackIp': 'Id1'},
  {'Node': '1', 'IdRackIp': 'Id2'},
  {'Node': '2', 'IdRackIp': 'Id3'},
  {'Node': '2', 'IdRackIp': 'Id4'}
]
```

I have recently started working on Python and I am getting trouble to sort it in this format. Can anyone help me to get this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally what you're looking for is:

```
dicts = []
for d in list_of_dicts:
    for i in d['IdRackIp']:
        dicts.append({'Node': d['Node'], 'IdRackIp': i})
```

This can be compacted using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries):

```
dicts = [{'Node': d['Node'], 'IdRackIp': i} for d in list_of_dicts for i in d['IdRackIp']]
```

The repetitive dictionary notation can further be compacted to:

```
dicts = [dict(d, IdRackIp=i) for d in list_of_dicts for i in d['IdRackIp']]
```

Credits for this last one entirely go to [Mezba メ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56538851/476), who remembered it first; but I thought it important to incorporate here too.

Comment: Beat me as well, damn you! Get my upvote.

Comment: @Finomnis It's not a race.

Comment: But if it were, he'd have won.

Comment: @Finomnis - If its a race at all, then its a race to make the best answer to the question. [fgitw](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/298072) is not always a good thing. You should vote on a post on its merit, not its speed

Comment: Relax, this question was easy, all the answers will be fine. But I'm not gonna post a second, identical answer to the question, that's why he won :)
Just have fun once in a while, don't everyone be so serious :)
If it makes you uncomfortable, I can delete my comments

Answer (score -1):

Here's a one liner:

```py
result = [dict(item, **{'IdRackIp': _id}) for item in list_of_dict for _id in item['IdRackIp']]
```

Comment: I was trying to remember this shorthand for merging dicts on the fly! Good catch. You could simply do `dict(item, IdRackIp=_id)` though.